# hive : ParseException line 3:23 cannot recognize input near 'from'

Tags: arrays, hadoop, struct

I tried to create this table :

```
create table tmp_test (
id_ string,
myelement array<struct<from:string>>
)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION '/donne/tmp_test'
```

And i have this error :

*Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 3:23 cannot recognize input near 'from' ':' 'string' in column specification.*

How can i escape words 'from', cause i must use this word ?

thxs for your help

Answer (score 1):

[FROM](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Keywords,Non-reservedKeywordsandReservedKeywords) is a reserved keyword in Hive.

Use backtick (`) to quote it,

```
create table tmp_test (
id_ string,
myelement array<struct<`from`:string>>
)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION '/donne/tmp_test';
```